# Zend Translate is killing my site performance

Tags: php, zend-framework, gettext

I have been using Zend Translate for some websites, on different VPSs. On one of them, the Zend Translate functions are painfully slow. I have no more than 30 or 40 strings, split in two different files, but eve so it takes a huge amount of time.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (PHP 5.3.10) with latest Zend Framework of the 1.x series (1.12.3). This problem is apparently absent on Ubuntu 10.04, with the same Zend Framework.

Everything gets stuck in  'Zend_Translate_Adapter_Gettext->_loadTranslationData', which takes some 700msec to complete.

I have no clues. I have tried experimentally to use APC on that server, but it does nothing to alleviate this problem.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Parsing .po files must be slow. My suggestion: ditch Zend_Translate and go with the native gettext extension (and compiled .mo files of course).

Comment: I am already using compiled .mo files, and that is why this is strange to me. Anyway, yes, I will certainly ditch that, if I don't find any solution quite soon :/

Comment: have you tried using the cache on Zend_Translate [REF] http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.adapter.html#zend.translate.adapter.caching